# How do I skip a GIT commit from a merge?

Tags: git

I have a question about undoing a commit in GIT.  There was a merge commit (a commit from a merge) that broke the branch and I'm trying to fix the problem.

The problem is:

Commit 1 - by a developer.  No bugs

Commit 2 - by a developer.  No bugs.  Everything copacetic here.

Merge commit 3 - by a developer from another remote GIT repo.  This is not a commit from the developer into the Git repo.  It's a commit because of a merge with another branch.  You can see the difference in the git log output - there's a "Merge: commit number" entry after the commit hexsum value.  This broke things and now compilation fails.

Commit 4 - by a developer.  Right after Merge commit #3.  Still broken because of the Merge commit #3.

We can wait for the developer who did the Merge commit 3 to fix it.  Unfortunately, he's on vacation for 2 weeks and he did a "commit and run".  And we don't want to wait for him to return.

What I would like to do is to fix the branch so that I can get commits #1, #2, ignore merge commit #3, and get commit #4.

I tried the "git rebase -i HEAD~4" command but unfortunately, this interactive command does NOT let you unpick Merge commits.  Merge commits aren't even listed for this command.

Is there another way to ignore a merge commit?

Comment: did you try to cherry-pick the commit?

Comment: It sounds like you need to undo a previous commit (i.e. commit #3) - did you try to `git revert` yet? (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes)

Comment: How do you cherry pick a commit?  Do you mean I manually diff the files from commit #2 and commit #4 and then apply the changes?

Comment: kram (upside down) - we did a git cherry pick.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1, preferred**

Just fix it. You're a team. Have one another's back.

**Option 2, reverse the commit**

```
git revert SHA_of_the_bad_commit_here
git commit -m "Reverting commit XXX by bad_bad_developer - it broke the build"
```

This doesn't change history and is quite a good option

** Option 3, another branch **

This could work if this is *not* a special branch (e.g. *develop*, *master*, or whatever important branches you have ) *or* if you are OK to work on another branch until _bad_bad_dev_ comes back and fixes the original branch.

Create a new branch from the commit2 -> switch to that new branch and apply commit 4 -> keep working

**Option 4, git reset**

This is the option by @ochi - it changes history and cause headaches if the branch is shared, which it seems to be the case.

Comment: We went with Option #3.

Option #1 would have been the best way but the developer didn't test his code before merge, didn't even attempt to test if it would compile, and just merged it  and took off, which is against standard operating procedures.

I won't clean up other people's mess if they break rules to create the mess.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reset to a certain commit (i.e. #2) and apply the changes in commit #4

```
git reset --hard <commit-#2-id>
git commit -m "commit #4"
git push
```

Comment: In a shared environment you most likely would have to `--force` which can lead to hard to solve issues.

Comment: @tymtam fair comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just revert back to Commit 2 , find the branch that was created for COmmit 4, then merge that branch into whatever branch this is in.